# Bootstrap 5 form validation - required & disabled

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I currently have a disabled input box. I use the box to display the sum of two range sliders, where I update the value of the box via JavaScript.

I currently require that the value of the box equals 100 before allowing the form to be submitted. Is there a work-around where I can still disable the box, where it will still adopt the same Bootstrap style formatting (change color from red to green, etc) as a non-disabled box with the 'require' option?

Following a suggestion here, I've updated the code snippet below to **almost** be what I want. The only thing that I'd like to change, is to make 'rSum', the box that displays the sum, disabled (while still keeping all the validation formatting features). Ideally, I want this sum to adopt the validation feedback rather than the sliders, or other mutable input objects.

```js
function checkSum() {
  let currSum = parseInt(document.getElementById('rSum').value);
  if (currSum != 100) {
    document.getElementById('rSum').setCustomValidity('Must sum to 100%');
    return false
  } else {
    document.getElementById('rSum').setCustomValidity('');
    return true
  }
}


function updateBoxes() {

const s1 = document.getElementById('range1');
const s2 = document.getElementById('range2');
let currSum = parseInt(s1.value) + parseInt(s2.value);

document.getElementById('rangeValue1').value = (s1.value)+"%";
document.getElementById('rangeValue2').value = (s2.value)+"%";

document.getElementById('rSum').value = (currSum)+"%";

}

//  This last function is the original bootstrap validation example, modified to call 'checkSum()' instead
(function () {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-validation')

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function (form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (!checkSum()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }

        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
})()
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form class="custom-validation" novalidate>

  <div class="mb-3 row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="rangeValue1" disabled>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-form-label">
      <input type="range" class="form-range" min="0" max="100" step="5" id="range1" value="0" onchange="updateBoxes()" >
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="mb-3 row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="rangeValue2" disabled>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-form-label">
      <input type="range" class="form-range" min="0" max="100" step="5" id="range2" value="0" onchange="updateBoxes()" >
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="mb-3 row">
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="rSum" placeholder="100%" required>
  <div class="valid-feedback">
    Looks good!
  </div>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Probabilities must add up to 100%
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="mb-3 row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 offset-md-1">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Made snippet of your code, it would help to add how you call your function perhaps - if inside a form include that form and whatever HTML triggers the call?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways to do this. Here I use an example form with some inputs that can be used in the slider validation (one is a range slider but could be a simple number input also).

I set an event handler for those elements, associate them using data attributes and then; very verbosely and a bit ugly for clarity, use them in a function.

```js
function checkSum(event) {
  const fearRequird = this.fearNeed;
  const myFear = event.target;
  const associated = document.querySelector(myFear.dataset.related);
  const result = this.sumEl;
  const thisValue = parseInt(myFear.value);
  const associatedValue = parseInt(associated.value);

  let currSum = thisValue + associatedValue;
  result.value = currSum;
  let isValidSlider = currSum >= fearRequird;
  result.classList.toggle("is-valid", isValidSlider);
  result.classList.toggle("is-invalid", !isValidSlider);
  let t = isValidSlider ? '' : `You Fear ${thisValue} and ${associatedValue} total ${currSum}. You need total ${fearRequird} fear`;
  result.setCustomValidity(t);

  result.closest('.form-group').querySelector('.invalid-feedback').textContent = t;
  return isValidSlider;
}

(function() {
  'use strict'
  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  let forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation');
  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false)
    });

  const fearNeed = 100;
  const myFears = document.querySelectorAll('.fear-factor');
  const needs = {
    fearNeed: fearNeed,
    sumEl: document.querySelector('#rSum')
  };
  myFears.forEach((fearElement) => {
    fearElement.addEventListener('change', checkSum.bind(needs), false);
  });
})();
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form class="row g-3 needs-validation mx-1 my-2" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="rSum" placeholder="100%" required>
    <div class="valid-feedback">
      Looks good!
    </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Fears must add up to 100%
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="validationCustomUsername" class="form-label">Fish Name</label>
    <div class="input-group has-validation">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend">Fish</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustomFishname" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Must catch a fish.
      </div>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks like an good catch!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="validationCustomFearMet" class="form-label">Scary cats fear</label>
    <div class="input-group has-validation">
      <input type="number" class="form-control fear-factor" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="13" id="validationCustomFearMet" data-related="#customRange3" required />
      <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend">%</span>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide scary cats fear as a percent 0-100.
      </div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide scary cats fear as a percent 0-100.
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mx-1">
    <label for="customRange3" class="form-label">Fear range</label>
    <input type="range" class="form-range fear-factor" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" data-related="#validationCustomFearMet" id="customRange3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
  </div>
</form>
```